# Find out if lat/lon coordinates fall inside a US State

Tags: python, geopy

Using Python, is there a function, library, or other way to check to see if a certain lat/lon coordinate pair fall within a defined geographical boundary such as a US state?

Example:

Does 32.781065, -96.797117 fall within Texas?

Comment: I found some links with the google search ["python reverse geocoding"](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+reverse+geocoding&oq=python+reverse+geocoding&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i59l2.3023j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Regarding the vote to close, I think that OP didn't particularly expect or require that a "tool, [third party] library or off-site resource" would be needed to solve the problem. But it is.

Comment: I'm confused. Was there a vote to close this question? If so, why? I asked an honest question that I'm sure would be useful to others.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [reverse geocode](https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder) library, and then check that the "admin1" area is a specific US state.

It converts lat/lon coordinates into dictionaries like:

```
{
  'name': 'Mountain View', 
  'cc': 'US', 
  'lat': '37.38605',
  'lon': '-122.08385', 
  'admin1': 'California', 
  'admin2': 'Santa Clara County'
}
```

Comment: Excellent find!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [geocoder library](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder#installation) which you can install using `pip install geocoder`.

```
import geocoder

results = geocoder.google('32.781065, -96.797117', reverse = True)

print(results.current_result.state_long)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to send a request to the [Google geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#reverse-example).

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on mathisonian's answer.

```
import reverse_geocoder

#create a list of US states (and the District of Columbia)
state_names = ["Alaska", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "Arizona", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "District of Columbia","Delaware", "Florida","Georgia", "Hawaii", "Iowa", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Massachusetts", "Maryland", "Maine", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Missouri", "Mississippi", "Montana", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Nebraska", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "Nevada", "New York", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina","South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Virginia", "Vermont", "Washington", "Wisconsin", "West Virginia", "Wyoming"]

#get the metadata for the latitude and longitude coordinates
results = reverse_geocoder.search((32.781065, -96.797117))

#check if the location is a US state (the 'admin1' variable is where US states are listed)
if results[0]['admin1'] in state_names:
  print(results[0]['admin1'])
```

That should print "Texas".